# Are all myths superstitions, or are all superstitions myths?

Tags: meaning, nouns, synonyms, hypernyms

Are all myths superstitions, or is it the other way around, i.e. all superstition being myths?

Or can these words basically be used interchangeably?

The dictionary definitions of these words seem somewhat vague.

Comment: “Myths,” CS Lewis told JRR Tolkien, were “lies and therefore worthless, even though breathed through silver.” “No,” Tolkien replied. “They are not lies.”

Comment: Tolkien postulates a gradual distancing in the prologue to The Lord of the Rings: History became Legend; Legend became Myth. I'd put the vast majority of the Robin Hood stories in the 'legend' class, and the 'Arthurian Legends', with their frequent allusions to the supernatural, largely in the 'myth' class.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Myth in its proper sense is a very rich and deep word, meaning a reflection of truth. Myths can be true, and they are intended to convey truth even when they are not, strictly speaking, true. Myth is a means of communicating non-empirical truth in an oral culture.

Superstition can have its roots in mythology, but is usually about actions performed without a proper understanding of the reasons.

Both words can have both negative and positive implications.

Comment: I would say that if you want positive implications for *superstition*, you use another word such as *folklore*.

Comment: "Both words can have both negative and positive implications." Way to go, Schroedingers Cat!

Comment: @TimLymington Yes - good choice.

Comment: Just in case you felt I was making a jibe at you - I was referencing Schroedinger's cat when I quoted "... both positive and negative"

Comment: @asymptotically Referring to the QM thought experiment in which a cat is sealed in a box with a deadly object?

Comment: Kudos for mentioning oral culture. In our technology-based book ridden society the memory-based literature is seldom respected.

Comment: rich and deep word? Myths do not always reflect the truth. I find this answer to be overly casual. Not all superstition comes from myths.

Answer (score 15):

> > “Myths,” CS Lewis told JRR Tolkien, were “lies and therefore worthless, even though breathed through silver.”
> >
> > “No,” Tolkien replied. “They are not lies.”

A ***myth*** is an echo of temporally distant events remolded into archetypes easily transmitted through oral histories.  Myths are closely related to ***legends***.

A ***superstition*** is “an unreasoning awe or fear of something unknown, mysterious, or imaginary, especially in connexion with religion.” [OED]

The two words need not intersect.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that quote?

Comment: @DJClayworth: I'm unsure about the "They are not lies" bit. But Tolkien did [pen a poem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mythopoeia_(poem)) in reply.

Comment: @coleopterist *Blessed are the legend-makers with their rhyme / of things not found within recorded time. ... They have seen Death and ultimate defeat, / and yet they would not in despair retreat, / but oft to victory have tuned the lyre / and kindled hearts with legendary fire, / illuminating Now and dark Hath-been / with light of suns as yet by no man seen.* [reference](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/mythopoeia.html)

Answer (score 6):

These two words are not interchangeable.

A myth is "any invented story, idea, or concept"

A superstition is "a belief or notion, not based on reason or knowledge, in or of the ominous significance of a particular thing, circumstance, occurrence, proceeding, or the like."

So the two words are definitely not interchangeable.

"Elephants are scared of mice" is a myth.

"Walking under a ladder brings bad luck" is a superstition.

A superstition is usually a belief that some event will bring either bad or good luck. In the broadest possible sense, a superstition could be considered a type of myth, but not vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

Two definitions of **myths** per Merriam-Webster are:

*1a : a usually traditional story of ostensibly historical events that serves to unfold part of the world view of a people or explain a practice, belief, or natural phenomenon*

*b : parable, allegory*

*2a : a popular belief or tradition that has grown up around something or someone; especially : one embodying the ideals and institutions of a society or segment of society*

*b : an unfounded or false notion*

**Myths** refer to archetypal themes.  Sometimes they are revered and sometimes they are debunked. Often they are so fanciful that their reality is highly unlikely (at least to the scientifically oriented). Sometimes they are unverifiable merely because they relate to things for which, thought feasible, there is no satisfactory scientific or historical record.

When a **myth** as described in the second definition is debunked and that debunking is widely disseminated, the myth dies.

**Superstitions** are beliefs that are not scientifically supportable (at least by current science). They are often tied to some religious belief, but sometimes just to random custom, e.g. *step on a crack, break your mother's back*.

If a reliable and valid proof of a *superstition* is later demonstrated, it ceases to be *superstition* and becomes emerging science. Probably the theory of germs was originally considered to be a superstition. (Mere speculation on my part.)

Most often *superstitions* are prescriptive or prohibitory. Do something/avoid something or suffer the consequences.

Answer (score 2):

"Superstition" is generally defined as -- to take thefreedictionary.com as a source here -- "An irrational belief that an object, action, or circumstance not logically related to a course of events influences its outcome." A superstition is a claim of some supposed fact or relationship, like "if you break a mirror you'll get seven years bad luck" or "if a robin flies in your window, death will follow".

The word "myth" has multiple definitions.

Definition 1 in most dictionaries is that it is a "story" about gods or heroes. (We could discuss what makes some stories "myths" and other stories just ... "stories". But I don't think we need to get into that here.)

So a superstition is very different from definition #1 of a myth, because a superstition is not a story, it's just a statement. "If you break a mirror" etc is not a story: it has no plot, no characters beyond a generic "you", etc.

"Myth" often has a definition 2 that says something like, "a popular belief" or "a ficticious fact". Like someone may say, "It is a myth that blonde women are dumb," meaning that that statement is not true. This definition of myth could overlap with superstition, but they don't really mean the same thing. A superstition is generally understood to involve luck or magic; this definition of myth simply means "false claim", and is usually applied to things that have nothing to do with the supernatural. Callling something a myth is often a way to say it's not true without blatantly calling the person who said it a liar. Like if you say, "President Smith's claim that it was his jobs bill was what caused the stock market to go up is a myth", you are saying that the president's claim is not true, without explicitly saying that he is lying or stupid.

I see a couple of posters here have connected superstition with religion. I guess it depends on exactly how you define both words. I don't want to get into an argument about it, but I think such a connection is most often made by people who are denigrating someone else's religion or by atheists who are denigrating all religions. I have never heard anyone who was a serious believer of any religion refer to his own beliefs as "superstition". So I'd be cautious about using the word that way, unless it is your intent to insult someone's religion.

When we talk about superstition we are normally talking about things that are supposed to bring bad luck or good luck or cause some event that has no apparent causal relationship in any non-magical sense. I don't know of any religion that takes it as a point of doctrine that breaking a mirror will bring bad luck, for example. Calling something a superstition is normally understood to mean that it is irrational. If you say, "It is a doctrine of Christianity that Jesus Christ came back from the dead," that is a simple statement of fact. Of course many people doubt that that doctrine is true, but it is an undisputed fact that that is indeed a doctrine of orthodox Christianity. But if you say, "It is a superstition of Christianity that Jesus Christ came back from the dead", any Christian I know would interpret that as an insult, as saying that this belief is irrational and foolish. Of course if your intent is to call a belief irrational in an insulting way, then that may be an appropriate choice of words. But if you are trying to have a friendly conversation, use another word.

Comment: It’s a simple matter of conjugation:  *I am religious, you are credulous, he is superstitious.* One man’s faith is the next one’s belly-laugh.

Comment: @tchrit Exactly in line with the point I was trying to make.

Answer (score 2):

The English word Myth may be used in a sense which is somewhat similar to the usage for Superstition.  However Myth has many shades of meaning, and many contextual uses, which have completely different meanings.

Something is called a "myth" in the sense used by the show Mythbusters; This is very similar in meaning to a superstition, but both could simply be dropped and replaced with "lies" or "misinformation".

Something which is a "myth" in the literary, or cultural sense is not a lie, and there is no intent to deceive.  Myth refers to the powerful sense of meaning that certain stories have, even though they are not verifiable as history, or even though they are very unlikely to be true because they have elements that are either inconsistent, or supernatural, or otherwise, not very credible as literal history.  Myth is more than legend, even. It's some kind of collective social identity.

Answer (score 1):

- a myth is a kind of story. (they tend towards the made-up, fabulous, or magical, like stories of Roman gods, or anecdotes of political candidates)

  - sometimes a thing is called a myth when it is a supposed fact that turns out not to be true. This might be a simple statement-like fact (either historical or scientific-like) or a magical explanation .
- a superstition is a belief about a causal relation. (they are usually considered untrue and fabulous or magical)

The two are related in their sense of assumed tenuous relationship with truth, but they would only intersect (as descriptions of things) in something like 'just-so' stories, for example where the leopard got his spots. The second sense of myth, magical explanation, is synonymous with superstition. So some kinds of myths are superstitions (and some are not), but it would be misleading to say that a superstition is a kind of myth.

Answer (score 0):

Superstitions inevitably have to do with the supernatural, and are mostly the result of religious practice/belief.

Myths are supposed "facts" pertaining to the natural and are caused by popularity of the statement, and how many people believe it. Additionally, myths can be proved/disproved.

For example, it is a superstition that clinking your glass scares away the Devil. This can't be proved and pertains to the supernatural. It *is* a myth that the reason meteors start glowing is because of friction (see [this](http://listverse.com/2009/04/08/top-10-ridiculously-common-science-myths/)).

Comment: You are using *myth* to mean nothing more than *falsehood*.

Comment: Your comment about the falseness of the claim that the liquid leaving the lowest hole in the container in the experiment you mention would travel the greatest horizontal distance is not true. Of course, the holes have to be identical and of a size appreciable enough to allow spurting, and there needs to be freedom for the streams to drop unhindered, but I have seen this experiment performed successfully. The mathematics and physics of the situation also SUPPORTS the assertion rather than, as you claim, disproves it.

Comment: I you allow it to drop unhindered, a hole made at the lowest possible position will just spew out water which does not travel horizontally at all. For maximum horizontal range, the hole needs to be made halfway up the bottle.

Comment: @tchrist I have mentioned that myths can be 'proved or disproved'

Comment: @asymptotically Prove or disprove Romulus and Remus.

Comment: @tchrist There are two types of myths - ones which are mythological stories, which are not what I am talking about, and, well, just *myths* which are facts (not tales or stories) most people believe and are - generally - wrong.

Comment: See Luke's example - "Elephants are scared of mice" - that is a fact (which can be proved/disproved), and is *not* a story, though it may have originated from one.

Comment: The OED brands the secondary sense of **myth** of “an untrue or popular tale, a rumour” with its ***“colloquial”*** label. This is hardy the main sense, nor the uncolloquial one. That’s why Shroedingers Cat referred to *myth in its **proper** sense* in the answer given above; I assume that uses *proper* in opposition to *colloquial*.

Comment: @asymptotically: I believe you're missing something in your experiment description, such as "the bottle is resting on a surface which extends past the edge of the bottle on the side where the holes are made."  If the bottle were instead placed so that the hole is over empty space (which I believe is what Edwin meant by "drop unrestricted") then the lowest stream would indeed shoot out fastest and farthest.

Comment: @BenVoigt It doesn't matter if it is drop restricted or not. The vertical speeds of all jets at the beginning is 0, and accelerate at *g*, so they all reach the same height at the same time. The horizontal speed of the jet from the hole poked midway along the height is maximum, so at any point of time - even at infinity - the horizontal distance of the middle jet is the maximum. See [this](http://thehappyscientist.com/files/EOWpics/3holes/3%20holesb1.jpg). Even if it were at the edge of the table, the middle jet would have traveled the most when the three jets hit the ground.

Comment: @asymptotically: In your picture, the middle jet strikes farther from the bottle, but only because it has a much greater time to fall.

Comment: @BenVoigt As I said, when the jets reach a particular height, they have all been traveling for the same amount of time - vertically, at any instant, all their speeds are same. By s = ut + .5gt^2. u = 0 for all jets, hence s = .5gt^2. So at some point of time, they have all reached the same height.

Comment: For example, if you drop a ball from a cliff or throw it horizontally, they will both reach the ground at the same time, since vertical speeds are both zero, and vertical and horizontal motions are independent of each other

Comment: @asymptotically: Not if they start at different heights!  At any given time, they have all fallen the same distance (delta-h), but they are not at the same height (h).

Comment: @BenVoigt That distance is negligible when you're comparing it to the height of say, the ground. That too you say the the drop is not restricted - meaning it falls to infinite height. At that point, you can definitely ignore it. You still can even in this case

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4376/discussion-between-asymptotically-and-ben-voigt)

Comment: @asymptotically: That distance is NOT negligible in the picture you posted to "prove" your case.

Answer (score 0):

In Ancient Greek, *mythos* μῦθος is "a story or set of stories relevant to or having a significant truth or meaning for a particular culture, religion, society, or other group.. A tale, story, or narrative, usually verbally transmitted, or otherwise recorded into the written form from an alleged secondary source.. Anything delivered by *word of mouth*: a word, speech, conversation, or similar; a story, tale, or legend" [italics added]

https://etymologeek.com/eng/mythos

HENRY GEORGE LIDDEL, ROBERT SCOTT, A GREEK-ENGךISH LEXICON 1151: “word, speech […] II. story, narrative […] *without distinction of true or false*” (1843; 9th ed. 1928; reprinted 1968) [italics added].

(To be frank, I once posted a query here as to the possible connection between *myth* and *mouth*. I was demoted, so I am wary, but I will point to the above definitions that emphasize the oral quality of the mythic story, rather than the issue of its veracity. This, in contrast with OED's determination that myth is *"a purely fictitious narrative"*. I find that an overstatement.)

Cf. Deuteronomy 28:37 (*And thou shalt become an astonishment, a proverb* [=Heb.: *mashal*], *and a byword, among all the peoples whither the LORD shall lead thee away*,) where *mashal* is to be read not as a parable or allegory (as in post-biblical Hebrew) but rather as a sign for others (here indeed the phonetic similarity between *mashal/myth* seems happenstance, but conceptually the two words are akin to each other.)

Comment: ELU deals with words since entry into the English lexicon; any claims that words should mirror their original meanings in the source language (or even those on entry into the lexicon) more faithfully than they do in common usage are instances of the etymological fallacy.

Comment: I accept your comment. But surely original meanings cast a long shadow and influence the course of usage, even while they do not determine that course. I would submit that caution is necessary, but rejection shouldn't be taken for granted as an axiom.

Comment: Checking in a few reputable modern dictionaries, and for examples in COCA say, constitute the proper research.

Comment: Research - yes. Satiate the thirst for knowledge, curiosity, not always.  I accept your pointing out the *fallacy* as to *usage*. But I think that we use myths in a wider range than the "official" entries. Was Babe Ruth a myth in his own time? Wasn't he "real"?

Comment: COCA samples the spoken as well as the written word.