# Is there a word or short phrase to indicate a myth that is not true?

Tags: single-word-requests

People usually say "it is just a myth" to indicate they either don't believe it to be true, or that they are sure it is not true. However, this is inaccurate, as myths can be true or not true, or anything in between. "Myth" only means that there is no (or just anecdotal) evidence.

How can I accurately say that something is a myth **and** it's false.

Edit: I edited "not true" to "false". Myths are not binary. One answer provided a definition, in the sense of something which is believed to be true but it's not. However, not true and false are not necessarily the same. To not be able to prove something to be true is not the same as proving it to be false.

What I'm specifically looking for is to express that

A) Something it a myth

B) It has been (or can be) decisively proven to be false.

The importance is to **accentuate** part B. To answer this, do you really require a long list of examples where a myth is ambiguous, some believe it to be true, others don't believe it but no one can decisively prove anything?

Comment: Closely related: [Are myths superstitions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76842/are-all-myths-superstitions-or-are-all-superstitions-myths)

Comment: If, by definition, there is at most anecdotal evidence, in what sense can a myth be "true"?

Comment: Please provide examples of myths that are true, of myths that are not true, and of myths that are anything in-between. Otherwise it's not clear at all what you mean. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sure we have a word to describe stories which have been decisively proven false, but I can't think where the answer lies.

Answer (score 7):

Going by [the ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/myth),

> Definition of myth
>   noun
>
> 1. traditional story, especially one concerning the early history of a people or explaining a natural or social phenomenon, and typically involving supernatural beings or events
> 2. **widely held but false belief or idea**

So, as per sense 2, the word *myth* is eminently suitable :)

The adjective [apocryphal](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/apocryphal) can also be used to describe stories that are "*of doubtful authenticity, although widely circulated as being true*". Similarly, [fairy tale](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fairy+tale) might be suitable to describe a tale that talks of ages past and is understood to be untrue.

Comment: +1 for `apocryphal`: good word, although it doesn't (quite...) suggest that the story is actually proven false.

Answer (score 5):

Debunked?

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/debunked